# How to change design(e.g color) of button on press which is rendered through loop?

Tags: javascript, button, react-native, user-experience, uicolor

Hey guys can anybody help me way out of this problem. My problem is related to improving UX of the app. I have rendered accordion through a loop which renders data with a button on it. I wanted to change color of the button which is pressed thus helping in UX. But ran into problem as all buttons are turning their colors . The problem is i am rendering color from state can anybody help me out with some different solution.

This is the loop through which i am rendering accordion:

```
{this.state.services.map((tab, i) => {
            return(
              <ScrollView key={i} tabLabel={tab.category} style={{flex: 1}}>
                {tab.names.map((name, j) => this.renderRow(name))}
              </ScrollView>
            )
          })}
```

This is the render function:

```js
  renderRow (rowData) {
    var header = (
      rowData.subGroup.length > 1 ? <View>
        <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
      </View>
      :
      <View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
          <Text>{rowData.subGroup[0].duration}Min</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>₹{rowData.subGroup[0].price.M ? rowData.subGroup[0].price.M : rowData.subGroup[0].price.F}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._add(rowData.subGroup[0])}>
          <View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>ADD</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    );

    var content = (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {rowData.subGroup.map((sg, i) => {

            return(
              sg.subGroup ? <View>
                  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Text>{sg.subGroup ? sg.subGroup : sg.name}</Text>
                    <Text>{sg.duration}Min</Text>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.price}>₹{sg.price.M ? sg.price.M : sg.price.F}</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._add(sg)}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>ADD</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              :
              <View></View>
            )

        })}
      </View>
    );

    return (
      <Accordion
        key={rowData.name}
        header={header}
        content={content}
        easing="easeOutCubic"
      />
    );
  }
```

can anybody guide me through different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found out the solution just wrote a simple function and returned true or false. Based on the returned value and ternary operator i change style of selected value

here is a solution:

```
  <View style={this._toggleServiceButtonView(sg) ? styles.removeView : styles.buttonView}>
    <Text style={this._toggleServiceButtonView(sg) ? styles.removeText : styles.buttonText}>
      {this._toggleServiceButtonView(sg) ? 'REMOVE' : 'ADD'}
    </Text>
  </View>
```

Here is the function in which i am just checking if the selected value is in cart array to return true.

```
_toggleServiceButtonView(data) {
    return this.state.cartArr.length != 0 && this.state.cartArr.findIndex((service) => {
      if(service.service._id === data._id){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }) !== -1
  }
```